# "Payment received" event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, payment-methods, payment

I'm making a sponsorship module and I need to find when a godson has paid his first order. For that matter, I have to use an event observer, but I can't find which. My customers can pay by credit card and by check.

It is difficult to understand Magento's mess around payment, sorry about that, but I'm truly lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to hook into sales_order_payment_pay

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365930/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-payment-received-in-magento for a step-by-step on how to do this, and use http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8 for a list of observers (I don't see the 1.9 list yet, but it is very similar)